# Runtime error when removing an element from an array in Swift 4

Tags: swift

I wrote this simple algorithm to remove duplicate values from the input array, but I get a runtime error for the line where I remove the element from the array, error happens at this line `array.remove(at: i)`. I am using Codepair with Swift 4.

```
 func unique(_ arr:[Int]) -> [Int] {
   var array = arr
   var uniqueSet = Set<Int>()
   for i in 0 ..< array.count {
       if uniqueSet.contains(array[i]) {
           print("remove \(arr[i]) for i \(i) from array")
           array.remove(at: i)
       } else {
           print("insert \(arr[i]) into set")
           uniqueSet.insert(array[i])
       }
   }
   return array
 }
 print(unique([1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6]))
```

Comment: FYI - this is a good opportunity to use the debugger. Step through your code line by line and see the value of `i` at the time of the crash and the value of `array`. Think about what's going on during the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is inserting and deleting from the array while looping through it , which will make it crash or loop forever

No need for that you can

```
let dupArr = [1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6]
let result = Set(dupArr).sorted()   //  [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
```

Also if you want it manual

```
func unique(_ arr:[Int]) -> [Int] {

   var result = [Int]()

   for item in arr {

       if !result.contains(item) {

          result.append(item)
       }
   }

  return result
}
```